# Write protect a stack page on AIX?

Tags: memory, aix

I've a program where argv[0] gets overwritten from time to time. This happens (only) on a production machine which I cannot access and where I cannot use a debugger. In order to find the origin of this corruption, I'd like to write protect this stack page, so that any write access would be turned in a fault, and I could get the address of the culprit instruction.

The system is an AIX 5.3 64 bits based. When I try to invoke mprotect on my stack page, I get an ENOMEM error. I'm using gcc to generate my program.

On a Linux system (x86 based) I can set a similar protection using mprotect without trouble.

Is there any way to achieve this on AIX. Or is this a hopeless attempt?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/mprotect.htm - given that you seem to be restricted to pages that have been mmap'd (and a few other things), I doubt you can change the stack protection modes. (But I'm not familiar enough with this to answer.)

Answer (score 0):

On AIX, `mprotect()` requires that requested pages be shared memory or memory mapped files only.    On [AIX 6.1 and later](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/mprotect.htm), you can extend this to the text region, shared libraries, etc, with the `MPROTECT_TXT` environment variable.

You can however use the [`-qstackprotect` option](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.0/com.ibm.xlc131.aix.doc/compiler_ref/opt_stackprotect.html) on XLC 11/AIX 6.1TL4 and later.  "Stack Smashing Protection" is designed to protect against exactly the situation you're describing.

On AIX 5.3, my only suggestion would be to look into building with a toolset like [Parasoft's Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/product/insure/).   It would locate errant writes to your stack at runtime.  It's pretty much the best (and now only) tool in the business for AIX development.    We use it in house and its invaluable when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a workaround for this problem is to move processing over to a pthread thread. On AIX, pthread thread stacks live in the data segment which can be mprotected (as opposed to the primordial thread, which cannot be mprotected). This is the way the JVM (OpenJDK) on AIX implements stack guards.